# Solution of an IVP cannot be extended beyond an Interval.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following  differential equation

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 1 + y^2$ , $y(0) = 1$

I need to show the solution cannot be extended beyond
$(-3\pi/4, \pi/4)$

By uniqueness and existence theorem I can get an interval which guarantees a unique solution, but I don't really understand how should I use this to prove the above claim ?

A complete solution will be helpful here, since I am really struggling with these kind of problems.

Comment: This sort of problem is most easily proved by actually solving the equation rather than invoking a theorem

Comment: @NinadMunshi: The solution I get is : $y  = tan(x + \pi/4)$, now how should I proceed?

Comment: ...what is the domain of tan ? You already did the hard part

Comment: @NinadMunshi: $x \in \mathbb{R} - \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=dx$$
$$x+C=\arctan y;\;y(0)=1\to C=\arctan 1=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$x +\frac{\pi}{4}=\arctan y$$
RHS range is $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

thus for the LHS must be $-\frac{\pi}{2}<x+\frac{\pi}{4}<\frac{\pi}{2}$

and the solution $y=\tan \left(x+\pi/4 \right)$ is valid only when $-\frac{3}{4}  \pi < x< \frac{\pi }{4}$

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you can integrate this differential equation as $y(x)= \tan(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$.

From there, you can prove the desired result.